# Doubts about clustering methods for tweets

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering

I'm fairly new to clustering and related topics so please forgive my questions.

I'm trying to get introduced into this area by doing some tests, and as a first experiment I'd like to create clusters on tweets based on content similarity. The basic idea for the experiment would be storing tweets on a database and periodically calculate the clustering (ie. using a cron job). Please note that the database would obtain new tweets from time to time.

Being ignorant in this field, my idea (probably naive) would be to do something like this:

```
1. For each new tweet in the db, extract N-grams (N=3 for example) into a set
2. Perform Jaccard similarity and compare with each of the existing clusters. If result > threshold then it would be assigned to that cluster
3. Once finished I'd get M clusters containing similar tweets
```

Now I see some problems with this basic approach. Let's put aside computational cost, how would the comparison between a tweet and a cluster be done? Assuming I have a tweet Tn and a cluster C1 containing T1, T4, T10 which one should I compare it to? Given that we're talking about similarity, it could well happen that sim(Tn,T1) > threshold but sim(Tn,T4) < threshold. My gut feeling tells me that something like an average should be used for the cluster, in order to avoid this problem.

Also, it could happen that sim(Tn, C1) and sim(Tn, C2) are both > threshold but similarity with C1 would be higher. In that case Tn should go to C1. This could be done brute force as well to assign the tweet to the cluster with maximum similarity.

And last of all, it's the computational issue. I've been reading a bit about minhash and it seems to be the answer to this problem, although I need to do some more research on it.

Anyway, my main question would be: could someone with experience in the area recommend me which approach should I aim to? I read some mentions about LSA and other methods, but trying to cope with everything is getting a bit overwhelming, so I'd appreciate some guiding.

From what I'm reading a tool for this would be hierarchical clustering, as it would allow regrouping of clusters whenever new data enters. Is this correct?

Please note that I'm not looking for any complicated case. My use case idea would be being able to cluster similar tweets into groups without any previous information. For example, tweets from Foursquare ("I'm checking in ..." which are similar to each other would be one case, or "My klout score is ..."). Also note that I'd like this to be language independent, so I'm not interested in having to deal with specific language issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like to me that you are trying to address two different problems in one, i.e. "syntactic" and "semantic" clustering. They are quite different problems, expecially if you are in the realm of short-text analysis (and Twitter is the king of short-text analysis, of course).

"Syntactic" clustering means aggregating tweets that come, most likely, from the same source. Your example of Foursquare fits perfectly, but it is also common for retweets, people sharing online newspaper articles or blog posts, and many other cases. For this type of problem, using a N-gram model is almost mandatory, as you said (my experience suggests that N=2 is good for tweets, since you can find significant tweets that have as low as 3-4 features). Normalization is also an important factor here, removing RT tag, mentions, hashtags might help.

"Semantic" clustering means aggregating tweets that share the same topic. This is a much more difficult problem, and it won't likely work if you try to aggregate random sample of tweets, due to the fact that they, usually, carry too little information. These techniques might work, though, if you restrict your domain to a specific subset of tweets (i.e. the one matching a keyword, or an hashtag). LSA could be useful here, while it is useless for syntactic clusters.

Based on your observation, I think what you want is syntactic clustering. Your biggest issue, though, is the fact that you need online clustering, and not static clustering. The classical clustering algorithms that would work well in the static case (like hierarchical clustering, or union find) aren't really suited for online clustering , unless you redo the clustering from scratch every time a new tweet gets added to your database. "Averaging" the clusters to add new elements isn't a great solution according to my experience, because you need to retain all the information of every cluster member to update the "average" every time new data gets in. Also, algorithms like hierarchical clustering and union find work well because they can join pre-existant clusters if a link of similarity is found between them, and they don't simply assign a new element to the "closest" cluster, which is what you suggested to do in your post.

Algorithms like MinHash (or SimHash) are indeed more suited to online clustering, because they support the idea of "querying" for similar documents. MinHash is essentially a way to obtain pairs of documents that exceed a certain threshold of similarity (in particular, MinHash can be considered an estimator of Jaccard similarity) without having to rely on a quadratic algorithm like pairwise comparison (it is, in fact, `O(nlog(n))` in time). It is, though, quadratic in space, therefore a memory-only implementation of MinHash is useful for small collections only (say 10000 tweets). In your case, though, it can be useful to save "sketches" (i.e., the set of hashes you obtain by min-hashing a tweet) of your tweets in a database to form an "index", and query the new ones against that index. You can then form a similarity graph, by adding edges between vertices (tweets) that matched the similarity query. The connected components of your graph will be your clusters.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, I'm more interested in the "syntactic" case given that I'd like to use this for several languages, so issues like stemming or other specific issues would be a lot of extra work. When you say using N-gram with N=2 do you mean chars or words? As I said before, language independence would be needed so generating "words" wouldn't make sense in some languages.

Comment: BTW I did some testing with N=3 but the results weren't that great. Using Jaccard on the same tweets which only differed in the name mentioned (ie. about 14-16 out of 120 chars) gave a similarity of 70%. I presume N=3 adds more noise than needed in cases like this and perhaps N=2 would be a better take. Regarding MinHash, I've been reading about it and looks promising, but could you suggest me some resource that explains what hash generators are best for this? Thank you.

Comment: With N=2 I mean words. I think a 2-char model will yield a lot of false positives, since the number of possible features will be rather low, and language biased. I have no experience with non-latin languages, therefore I don't know if you can adapt a word model to those languages. As for MinHash, I recommend reading the original paper by A. Broder, which you can find [here](http://gatekeeper.dec.com/ftp/pub/dec/SRC/publications/broder/positano-final-wpnums.pdf). He uses Rabin fingerprints, but you can also check the simpler [Universal Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing).

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a lot like [canopy pre-clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canopy_clustering_algorithm) to me.

Essentially, each cluster is represented by the *first object* that started the cluster.
Objects *within* the *outer* radius join the cluster. Objects that are not *within* the *inner* radius of at least one cluster start a new cluster. This way, you get an overlapping (non-disjoint!) quantization of your dataset. Since this can drastically reduce the data size, it can be used to speed up various algorithms.

However **don't expect useful results from clustering tweets**. Tweet data is just to much noise. Most tweets have just a few words, too little to define a good similarity. On the other hand, you have the various retweets that are near duplicates - but trivial to detect.

So **what would be a good cluster of tweets**? Can this n-gram similarity actually capture this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Never heard of this clustering method so there goes something to the queue of "things to read". Regarding your last question, I honestly don't have an answer for that, but given the short length of the data, I thought this could help in capturing many cases like difference in punctuation, case, etc. Any alternatives suggested by you experts would be appreciated.

Comment: My opinion is that results derived from Twitter are useless beyond word counting, sorry.